# Como usar CommandParameter no Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin-forms

Boa tarde. Tenho um botão que é montado da seguinte forma:

```html
<ImageButton 
    Source="{local:EmbeddedImage ResourceId=CreativeAutoMobile.Midia.btnfoto.png}" 
    BackgroundColor="#c3c3c3"
    WidthRequest="50"
    CornerRadius="10"
    Clicked="BtnEnviarFotos_Click"
    BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference listaVistorias}, Path=BindingContext}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference item}, Path=BindingContext}">
</ImageButton>
```

Ele está funcionando, porém eu preciso refazer isso usando código em C#, e estou com dúvidas na sintaxe de como deve ser feito o Binding e como deve ser usado o CommandParameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No XAML

```
<ImageButton 
    Source="{local:EmbeddedImage ResourceId=CreativeAutoMobile.Midia.btnfoto.png}" 
    BackgroundColor="#c3c3c3"
    WidthRequest="50"
    CornerRadius="10"
    Clicked="BtnEnviarFotos_Click"
    CommandParameter="{Binding PARAMETRO}">
</ImageButton>
```

Modelo de classe c#

```
public class NOMEQUALQUER
{
  public string PARAMETRO{ get; set;}
}
```

View code-behind C#

```
 this.BindingContext = new NOMEQUALQUER(){ PARAMETRO = "valor desejado"}
```